# Is there an equivalent of geth console in EOS?

Tags: eosjs

I have used geth and web3. Is there something similar for EOS? I saw already eosjs exists.

Answer (score 1):

[`cleos`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/cleos-overview)

> `cleos` is a command line tool that interfaces with the REST API exposed by nodeos. In order to use `cleos` you will need to have the end point (IP address and port number) to a `nodeos` instance and also configure `cleos` to load the `eosio::chain_api_plugin`.